# Pulling more than 10 records for proof of delivery API from NetSuite

Tags: netsuite

Is there any way we can pull more than 10 records from workwave POD Api for more than 10 records?

Whenever I call workwave API through Map/Reduce script it's giving me an error message to slow down. Has anyone got this experience and how they did they manage to achieve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the List Orders or Get Orders API, there is a throttling limit - "Leaky bucket (size:10, refill: 1 per minute)".  However, both those APIs allow for retrieving multiple orders in a single call.  My suggestion would be to restructure your script so that instead of making the call to Workwave in the reduce stage for a single order, you make it in the Get Input Data stage for all orders you want to operate on, and map the relevant data to the corresponding NetSuite data in the Map stage before passing in through to the Reduce stage.

In other words, you make one call listing multiple order ids rather than multiple calls listing one order id.